# FullPage.js - Move slide to the right when background videos loop

Tags: javascript, html, video, fullpage.js, autoplay

I am using [FullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) on the following website: http://servicetrackingsystems.com/index.html

I have two slides on the first section that slide over to to the right every 12 seconds, and my FullPage.js function is customized as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['Home', 'Products', 'Services', 'AboutUs', 'Clients', 'Contact'],
        menu: '#menu',
        css3: true,
        scrollOverflow:true,
        fixedElements: '.nav_bar',
        slidesNavigation: true,
        afterLoad: function(anchor, index){
          if(index == 1){
              $('.nav_bar').fadeOut();
               idInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                }, 12700);
          }else{
              $('.nav_bar').fadeIn();
              clearInterval(idInterval);
          }
        }
    });
});
```

And the videos are embedded in each slide as follows:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="img/bg/home1.jpg" id="bgvid1">
    <source src="video/home1_v3.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/home1_v3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video autoplay loop poster="img/bg/home2.jpg" id="bgvid2">
    <source src="video/home2_v3.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/home2_v3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Now here is the issue:**

Each video is exactly 12 seconds long. The $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight(); function only seems to work in the "afterLoad" callback, which fires once the entire page and all elements are finished loading.

**In Chrome:** The first background video starts playing once the entire page finishes loading, and the slide moves to the right exactly when each video loops so you don't see either video jump when it starts over.

**In Firefox:** The first background video starts playing immediately, even while the rest of the site is loading so the $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight(); interval begins partway through the video, resulting in very obvious jumps when the video loops.

**So my question is how can I adjust my script to work the same in all browsers, and to have the $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight(); transition happen exactly when each autoplaying video loops. Thank you in advance to the help!**

Comment: Related with this open issue: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it is going to work in all browsers, I know some, Safari for instance, used to block autoplay and non-interactive js play() method by default and may still do. In any case, here is the code for you:

```
$(function () {
    var isContinuousLoop = true;
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
            if (1 == index) {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1, 0);
            }
        },
        onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
            if (1 == index) {
                $('#bgvid1').get(0).pause();
                $('#bgvid2').get(0).pause();
            }
        },
        afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
            if (1 == index) {
                var $vid = (0 == slideIndex) ? $('#bgvid1') : $('#bgvid2');
                var callback = function () {
                    $vid.get(0).play();
                    console.log('playing video ' + index + ' ' + slideIndex);
                    $vid.on('ended', function () {
                        $vid.off('ended');
                        $vid.get(0).pause();
                        var nextSlideIndex = (0 == slideIndex) ? 1 : 0;
                        if (isContinuousLoop || 1 == nextSlideIndex) {
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1, nextSlideIndex);
                        }
                    });
                };
                if ($vid.get(0).readyState > 3) {
                    callback();
                } else {
                    $vid.on('canplay', function() {
                        $vid.off('canplay');
                        callback();
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {
            var $vid = (0 == slideIndex) ? $('#bgvid1') : $('#bgvid2');
            $vid.get(0).pause();
            console.log('stopping video ' + index + ' ' + slideIndex);
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure to remove `autoplay` and `loop` attributes from your video tags.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I just tried the code you posted (which I realized was missing the closing parenthesis at the end of the $vid.on function) and removed the 'autoplay' attributes, but the videos did not play nor did the slide move to the right in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Good catch on the missing closing parenthesis, I have fixed it. Also added another listener for `canplay` event. If it does not work, it would be helpful to see what errors, if any, javascript spits.

Comment: I tried the new script and had the same results, though the background video started playing in Chrome after navigating away from Home and then navigating back (though it still did not slide to the right when the videos looped). I did not see any errors in the console.

Comment: @chadmadeit, see the edit to my answer. Hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: I think we're getting closer; I created a test site so I can show you what happens: http://servicetrackingsystems.com/videotest/

I removed both `loop` and `autoplay` on the videos, and used your script as-is while adding my fullpage options and removing the other scripts running on my site.

In Chrome, the video plays once the site is loaded but moves down to the next section once the video finishes instead of sliding right and playing the second video. It also stops playing if the #Home anchor link is added (when Home is clicked in the navigation). In Firefox, neither video plays at all.

Comment: @chadmadeit, see updated code. My last try ;) `isContinuousLoop` var at the top makes the videos loop or stop after one play.

Comment: You are a genius! The updated script works perfectly, and I see how you used the different callbacks to make the video loop function properly with the slide changes. Thanks a million for the help.